# How to call powershellscript file by passing path parameters from batch file with administrator privileges?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I know this has many answers on internet. I tried many of the sample codes but didn't work for me.
My requirement:
I have a powershell file CreateLink.ps1 this creates a link for the source folder($source) in destination folder($destination) with given link name($link). All three values are passed as arguments to this file. If I execute these with Powershell CLI as

```
C:\codedeploy\UAT\CreateLink.ps1 -source C:\Deployments\UAT\ -destination C:\codedeploy\UAT\release -link publish
```

soft link name publish of destinatio path C:\codedeploy\UAT\release is created in source path works fine. Below is CreateLink.ps1 code:

```
param([parameter(mandatory=$true)]
   $source,
   $destination,
   $link)
# Write-Host $source
# Write-Host $destination

if ($PSHOME -like "*SysWOW64*")
    {
        Write-Warning "Restarting this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell."

        # Restart this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell.
        #   (\SysNative\ redirects to \System32\ for 64-bit mode)

        & (Join-Path ($PSHOME -replace "SysWOW64", "SysNative") powershell.exe) -File `
        (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $MyInvocation.MyCommand) @args

        # Exit 32-bit script.

        Exit $LastExitCode
    }
    
# Release Root path
$release_root="$source"

# Deployment Root path
$deployment_root="$destination"

$symlink="$link"
# Make a Symlink path
$pathLink="$release_root\$symlink"

# Delete Symlink if exists and create anew
if((Test-Path $pathLink) -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output "Delete release Link: $pathLink<--"  
    # Powershell issue w/ Symlinks
    # https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/621
    # Fix: https://kristofmattei.be/2012/12/15/powershell-remove-item-and-symbolic-links/
    # rm -r $pathLink -Force 
    $RMDIR = "/c rmdir $pathLink"
    Start-Process cmd.exe  -ArgumentList $RMDIR -Wait
}
 
$MKLINK = "/c mklink /D $pathLink $deployment_root"
Start-Process cmd.exe  -ArgumentList $MKLINK -Wait
```

Now I need to call this powershell script file with arguments in a batch file after-deploy.bat in jenkins job. I tried below code:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\codedeploy\UAT\CreateLink.ps1 -source C:\Deployments\UAT\ -destination C:\codedeploy\UAT\release -link publish
```

and

```
powershell -Command "&{ Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-File C:\codedeploy\UAT\CreateLink.ps1' -source C:\Deployments\UAT\ -destination C:\codedeploy\UAT\release -link publish  -Verb RunAs}"
```

few other commands also didn't work for me. Any help on how to run this command with parameters from batch file would be appreciated. If possible please provide snippet of code.

Thanks in advance.